# SQL Reverse entire column

Tags: mysql, sql, reverse

is there a way to reverse an entire column?

Example:

```
ID    ColX    ColY    ColZ
0     001     010     100
1     002     020     200
2     003     030     300
```

shall be:

```
ID    ColX    ColY    ColZ
0     003     030     300
1     002     020     200
2     001     010     100
```

So the Column ID shall be reversed, the record with the last ID shall be the first, the second last the second first and so far.

The newest value has ID = 0 and the oldest ID = n, and this must be exactly reversed, else I cannot insert new records.

Comment: do you have gaps in your ID column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using variables:

```
SELECT t2.ID, ColX, ColY, ColZ
FROM (SELECT ID, ColX, ColY, ColZ,
             @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS rn
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS var
      ORDER BY ID) AS t1
INNER JOIN (  
      SELECT ID, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn          
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS var
      ORDER BY ID DESC) AS t2
ON t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY t2.ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64c67/3)

If you want to `UPDATE` then you can use the above query in an `UPDATE` statement like this:

```
UPDATE mytable AS t
INNER JOIN(
   SELECT ID, ColX, ColY, ColZ,
          @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS rn
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0) AS var
   ORDER BY ID) AS t1 ON t.ID = t1.ID
INNER JOIN (  
      SELECT ID, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn          
      FROM mytable
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS var
      ORDER BY ID DESC) AS t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
SET t.ID = t2.ID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d542f/2)

The above will work irrespective of the values of `ID` column.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have gaps in your ID, then you can use [this select query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63227/1):

```
SELECT
  max_id-ID AS ID,
  ColX,
  ColY,
  ColZ
FROM
  mytable CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS max_id FROM mytable) m
ORDER BY
  ID
```

or this [update query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aa69d/1) (but it will work only if ID is not a primary key):

```
UPDATE
  mytable m1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) as max_id FROM mytable) m
SET
  m1.ID = m.max_id - m1.ID
```

if it's a primary key you could use this:

```
UPDATE
  mytable m1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) as max_id FROM mytable) m
  INNER JOIN mytable m2 ON m1.ID = m.max_id - m2.ID
SET
  m1.ColX = m2.ColX,
  m1.ColY = m2.ColY,
  m1.ColZ = m2.ColZ
```

(please see it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fdc8/1))

but if your ID column has gaps (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 5, 6) you need a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  @x - t.id AS new_id,
  t.* 
FROM tab t,
( SELECT @x:= max(id+1) FROM tab ) m;

MariaDB [tmp]> SELECT
    ->   @x - t.id AS new_id,
    ->   t.*
    -> FROM tab t,
    -> ( SELECT @x:= max(id+1) FROM tab ) m;
+--------+----+--------+---------------------+
| new_id | id | action | date                |
+--------+----+--------+---------------------+
|      7 |  1 |      2 | 2015-09-24 15:28:30 |
|      6 |  2 |      4 | 2015-09-24 15:29:26 |
|      5 |  3 |      2 | 2015-09-24 15:30:01 |
|      4 |  4 |      3 | 2015-09-24 15:30:55 |
|      3 |  5 |      1 | 2015-09-24 16:07:25 |
|      2 |  6 |      5 | 2015-09-24 16:10:25 |
|      1 |  7 |      4 | 2015-09-24 16:29:26 |
+--------+----+--------+---------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```